# Installing SuperSU -- I found a binary problem

Tags: rooting, superuser, twrp, zip, htc-one-mini

Hi I am following Android Central's guide to root my HTC One Mini.
I got to this part:

> After installing the Custom Recovery, Your phone is now ready to get root access!
>
> Step 1: Connect your Phone to PC and Copy the SuperSU zip package to your phone SD Card.
>
> Step 2: Next, Reboot your HTC One Mini into Recovery Mode, Here is how to boot it:
>
> - Power off your phone
> - Now Press and Hold the Volume Down+Power buttons simultaneously for a few seconds.
> - Using the Volume Up/Down and Power button, Select the Recovery option from the menu.
>
> Step 3: Once booted into the Recovery Mode, Select the Install option and browse and select SuperSU zip file from the location where you’ve placed it.
>
> Step 4: Swipe the button which says, "Swipe to Confirm Flash".
>
> Step 5: Once it is done, Using the Reboot option, Reboot your phone.

The SuperSU zip file is in my internal memory but when I use "install" in TWRP and click on the zip file, it shows as empty in the folder (I know it's not empty).

Can I just unzip it on my PC and place the files in the right location on my phone?

I have downloaded the app SuperSU from the play store, tried running it only to get the message "there is no SU binary installed, and SuperSU cannot install it, this is a problem. If you just upgraded to android 4.3 , you need to manually re-root — consult the relevant forums for your device."

Could there be a problem with the way I unlocked the bootloader or would I not been able to have installed TWRP if I had screwed that up too?

Only my third root and I am no pro keyboard jockey so please, an idiots guide, if you would be so kind!

Comment: Following the two suggested solutions, could you please update the question and title to be specific, at the moment it is bit generic. I think you will get much more help in this way. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many questions here, so the actual problem is somewhat unclear. Getting root app from Playstore (on an unrooted device) will not work. Therefore, I suspect it all relates to problematic/corrupt SuperSU zip - without it, you can't get root functionality. It is not recommended to tamper with SuperSU zip file!

I suggest re-download SuperSU [here](http://download.chainfire.eu/supersu) and install it from recovery. If you can't install it, there could be other problems related to unsuccessful previous steps. Follow the rest of the steps from your guide and also seek help where the guide was originally posted. Good luck.

Comment: I know , many possible issues, the problem is, many guides seem to lack noob details in certain areas, so i have had to pick and chose bits of guides. Which is why i doubt i have the previous steps. The facts are: it is boot unlocked and TWRP is installed, i'm just not convinced to a professional degree. Maybe that is why the su zip in twrp is empty (apparently).

Comment: I understand. However, I think the problem is related to corrupted zip. TWRP (or any other recovery) neither has nor know about su zip, or any other zip, it will flash whatever you provide. That's why I suggest you re-download the actual sup zip from the link i shared, flash and see if it makes any difference. You can also update the original question with new information so others can better help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the guide is right (although a little vague)... 
So the only solution is that the zip file does not contain valid files. 
Try to search a new zip (specific for your device) and do again all the steps for the installation of supersu. 
I had a HTC One Mini too giving me the same problem. Found out the archive file was the problem. 
;)

Comment: by archive you mean the zip file? I have looked at it on my pc and it holds a host of info, it just seems TRWP can't see any of the files. Could it be the zip folder or should i just bin TWRP and try the CW method? Its been a week now and the money i have lost jailbreaking could have earned me a gold plated samsung note (god knows the ugly bugger needs it :)

Comment: Try downloading a different zip for your device ;)